# Group by and order with joining tables

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am having a problem sorting results from joining tables that have to be grouped in Mysql.

This is my tables setup.

Owners Table

- owner_id | owner_name
- 1        | Test owner 1
- 2        | Test owner 2
- 3        | Test owner 3

Images upload table

- image_id | image_name | ownerid | upload_date
- 1        | image1.jpg | 2       | 04-08-2009
- 2        | image2.jpg | 1       | 04-08-2009
- 3        | image3.jpg | 3       | 04-08-2009
- 4        | image4.jpg | 1       | 04-08-2009
- 5        | image5.jpg | 3       | 04-08-2009

The owner_id field is auto increment and so is the image_id fields.

What I am trying to do is get the owner_name for the last three uploaded images but not by the same owner. So in that example I would like it to return the following results.

Test owner 3
Test owner 1
Test owner 2

In that example the last owner to upload is Test owner 3 then Test owner 1 then Test owner 2.

I am using the following query but it does not return correct results

```
$sql = "SELECT u.*, s.* FROM UPLOAD_TBL u, OWNER_TBL s WHERE u.ownerid = s.owner_id
GROUP BY s.owner_id ORDER BY u.image_id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";
```

Any help setting up this query would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your SELECT statement look like now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can sort on the aggregated image id:

```
select s.owner_id, s.owner_name, max(u.imag_id) as last_image_id
from UPLOAD_TBL u
inner join OWNER_TBL s on s.ownerid = u.owner_id
group by s.owner_id, s.owner_name
order by last_image_id desc
limit 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You should simply group by owner_id and sort by upload_date DESC with LIMIT 3

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the following but it not giving back correct result.

$sql = "SELECT u.*, s.* FROM UPLOAD_TBL u, OWNER_TBL s WHERE u.ownerid = s.owner_id GROUP BY s.owner_id ORDER BY u.image_id DESC LIMIT 0, 3";

Comment: you are using aliases and they thed to cross my eyes but I thing your WHERE is misplaced

How About
SELECT * FROM OWNER_TBL LEFT JOIN UPLOAD_TBL ON owner_id=ownerid GROUP BY owner_id ORDER BY image_id DESC LIMIT 3


if you change the name of ownerid to owner_id in the 2nd table you can use the more simple
LEFT JOIN UPLOAD_TBL USING(owner_id)
(or any other join)

Sequ3L answer looks more elegant though
You should use EXPLAIN be able to know which one is faster

Comment: Thank you also for your help. This was also on track of what I needed. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
select
     distinct(owner_id), owner_name
from
     owner
inner join
     images on images.ownerid = owner.ownerid
order by
     images.upload_date desc limit 3
```

Comment: I'm no SQL-man, but shouldn't it be "FROM owner, images" since you" calling on images later on? Also, considering the wanted results, a left join should suffice, no?